# After installing MySQL 64 Bit on Snow Leopard is it possible to migrate the old data?

Tags: mysql, installation, osx-snow-leopard, migrate

in /usr/local i now have two mysql folders:

mysql-5.1.34-osx10.5-x86
mysql-5.1.37-osx10.5-x86_64

is it possible to migrate the data from my old mysql folder to the 64 bit one?

Thanks for help, dont really want to setup all my databases again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo mv /usr/local/mysql/data /usr/local/mysql/data.default
sudo mv /usr/local/mysql-5.1.34-osx10.5-x86/data /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Comment: sorry i dont really get it, it seems to me this is only renaming data to data.default?

Comment: The line you are interested in is the second: the first line allows you not to override mysql default data, while the second moves data from your previous intallation (which I suppose to be mysql-5.1.34-osx10.5-x86) to the version-independent directory. That do the trick for me ;)